# How to configure SweetAlert properly in Vue CLI

Tags: vuejs2, sweetalert2

Here are my configuration and stpes.

1- from terminal

```
npm install sweetalert2
```

2- in main.js

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

window.swal = Swal;
Vue.use(Swal);
// Toast config
const toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: 'top-end',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000,
  timerProgressBar: true,
  onOpen: (toast) => {
      toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
      toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
  }
});
window.toast = toast;
```

3- usage in views

```
toast.fire({
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Record has been updated.'
})
```

**Errors/Problem:**

```
237:5  error  'toast' is not defined  no-undef
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `const toast` use `window.toast`.